# Error when fetching data from API in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to fetch data from https://randomuser.me/api/ using react useEffect hook. Instead of the data to be displayed, I get an error, "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {number, name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead". I logged the results on my console, I realised the problem is from some of the nested objects, which outputs [object Object]. However, I don't know why some other nested objects display correctly. Below is my code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import '../../App.css';

const UsersList = () => {

  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setItems(result.results);
        },
        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      )
  }, [])

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  } else if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        {items.map((item, id) => (
        <div className="card content-panel" key={id}>
          
          <img src={item.picture.medium} alt="Profile pic" className="avatar-user-list" />

          <div className="card-text">
            <p>
              {item.name.first} &nbsp; {item.name.last}
            </p>
            <p>{item.location.street}</p>
            <p>{item.email}</p>
          </div>

          <div className="arrow-bg">
            <span className="arrow">&#x2192;</span>
          </div>        
        </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default UsersList;
```

Comment: Can you put an example of the api response ? Maybe the problem is the `{item.location.street}`, it's possible that it is an object with `number` and `name` properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

item.location.street is an object.

According to the response API, this is the street object.

```js
"street": {
   "number": 4850,
   "name": "Rue Dumenge"
},
```

Instead of rendering

```
<p>{item.location.street}</p>
```

You should render something like

```
<p>{`${item.location?.street?.number} ${item.location?.street?.name}`}</p>
```